# Ubuntu Phone no support for pop3, ical or webdav?

Tags: ubuntu-touch

Just got my Ubuntu phone yesterday, and it looks great.  However, there doesn't seem to be any support for basic stuff like ical, webdav or pop3.  I cant connect to my email account, or calendar or sync my account.  This is stuff that comes out of the box with all other platforms.  Are there any plans to support these basic technologies?  Is there a way to get a basic email client on the phone, for example?

Comment: Check out dekko in the store for a nice email client. Might work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can install "dekko" from the store, it's an email client
https://appstore.bhdouglass.com/app/dekko.dekkoproject

There is also a calendar application and you can sync google calendar
https://appstore.bhdouglass.com/app/com.ubuntu.calendar

Support for other types of accounts is going to come but not being worked on yet...